# Concatenating two fields in a collect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails 2.3.5

I'm not having any luck searching for an answer on this.   I know I could just write out a manual sql statement with a concat in it, but I thought I'd ask:

To load a select, I'm running a query of shift records.  I'm trying to make the value in the select be shift date followed by a space and then the shift name.   I can't figure out the syntax for doing a concat of two fields in a collect.   The Ruby docs make it looks like plus signs and double quotes should work in a collect but everything I try gets a "expected numeric" error from Rails.

```
  @shift_list =  [a find query].collect{|s| [s.shift_date + " " + s.shift_name, s.id]}
```

Thanks for any help - much appreciated.

Comment: Is `shift_date` a `String`, or a `DateTime` or `Date`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing what `s` is going to be or what type `s.shift_date` and `s.shift_name` are but maybe you're looking for this:

```
collect{|s| ["#{s.shift_date} #{s.shift_name}", s.id]}
```

That is pretty much the same as:

```
collect{|s| [s.shift_date.to_s + ' ' + s.shift_name.to_s, s.id]}
```

but less noisy.